# How can I pass through file name to the "img src"?

Tags: php, image, html

I have a page that displays a default image using the following code:

```
echo "<tr><td valign='top' colspan='4' align='center'> <img src='../wp-content/gallery/playerphotos/NoPhotoAvailable.png' width='180' height='180' border='1'></td></tr>";
```

I also have a variable available $row['lng_RecordID_PK'].

I would like to pass the variable through as the file name.

If there is a matching file in the /playerphoto/ folder, display that image.  Otherwise, display the default image "NoPhotoAvailable.png".

Thanks for your help with this one.

Comment: Whats the value of this  $row['lng_RecordID_PK'] variable

Comment: It is usually a number between 1-2000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to define the location of the image you're looking for:

```
$fileLocation = "./playerphoto/" . $row['lng_RecordID_PK'];
```

I'm not sure of the path to that folder, replace the "./playerphoto/" with the correct relative path. If the value of $row['lng_RecordID_PK'] does not return the file extension, you need to add `. '.png'` or whatever your extension is to the end of that line, before the `;`.

Then check if it exists, if it doesn't use your default location:

```
if (!file_exists($fileLocation)) {
    // Change the file location if it does not exist.
    $fileLocation = "../wp-content/gallery/playerphotos/NoPhotoAvailable.png";
}
```

Then you can echo your  element with the correct src:

```
echo "<tr><td valign='top' colspan='4' align='center'> <img src='" . $fileLocation . "' width='180' height='180' border='1'></td></tr>";
```

Comment: Here is the code I created from your suggestion:

    $playerfileLocation = "../wp-content/gallery/playerphotos/" . $row['lng_RecordID_PK'] . ".jpg";


if (file_exists($playerfileLocation))
    echo "<tr><td valign='top' colspan='4' align='center'> <img src='$playerfileLocation' width='180' height='180' border='1'></td></tr>";
else
    echo "<tr><td valign='top' colspan='4' align='center'> <img src='../wp-content/gallery/playerphotos/NoPhotoAvailable.png' width='180' height='180' border='1'></td></tr>";

Is there something wrong with my syntax?  The variable I'm passing through is "1539".

Answer (score 0):

```
if (file_exists($yourFilePath))
    echo "<tr><td valign='top' colspan='4' align='center'> <img src='$yourFilePath' width='180' height='180' border='1'></td></tr>";
else
    echo "<tr><td valign='top' colspan='4' align='center'> <img src='../wp-content/gallery/playerphotos/NoPhotoAvailable.png' width='180' height='180' border='1'></td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [file_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)

```
if(file_exists($row['lng_RecordID_PK']))
   $filename = $row['lng_RecordID_PK'];
else
   $filename = "NoPhotoAvailable.png"; // Adjust the path

...
...
<img src="$filename" />
```

Comment: I will always have the variable...but only sometimes have the image.  How would I format the if statement to include the path to the jpg file:

""../wp-content/gallery/playerphotos/"

Answer (score 0):

```
//if $row['lng_RecordID_PK']. has file path as well
if(file_exists($row['lng_RecordID_PK'])) {
  $imageFile = $row['lng_RecordID_PK'];
}
else {
  $imageFile = 'NoPhotoAvailable.png';
}
echo "<tr><td valign='top' colspan='4' align='center'> <img src='".$imageFile."' width='180' height='180' border='1'></td></tr>";
```